# how to design a table based on this json

Tags: mysql, json, database, database-design, relational-database

I need a bit of help organizing a database. Frankly, I don't really know what I'm doing, but I do have the result in mind. For now, I can't figure out how do I design my database.

The JSON source is the output from a reporter from Jasmine Matchers(protractor), and the reason for adding this to a database, is for storing my protractor tests results. I'm an automation developer, with some express and angular knowledge, not much. Basically, I'm trying to build a reporter and learn.

I already know how to push the data to the database, I linked them, but I do not really know how do I structure the database.

I have the following JSON. But what columns do I need in my database?

```
{
    "suite1": {
        "id": "suite1",
        "description": "test suite for home",
        "fullName": "test suite for home",
        "failedExpectations": [],
        "status": "finished",
        "specs": [
            {
                "id": "spec0",
                "description": "should be able to login and see the homepage",
                "fullName": "test suite for home should be able to login and see the homepage",
                "failedExpectations": [],
                "passedExpectations": [],
                "pendingReason": "",
                "status": "passed"
            },
            {
                "id": "spec1",
                "description": "should be able to change stuff on homepage",
                "fullName": "test suite for home should be able to change stuff on homepage",
                "failedExpectations": [
                    {
                        "matcherName": "toContain",
                        "message": "Expected undefined to contain 'asd'.",
                        "stack": "Error: Failed expectation\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\test\\e2e\\specs\\test1__spec.js:30:21)\n    at C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:112:25\n    at new ManagedPromise (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:1067:7)\n    at ControlFlow.promise (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2396:12)\n    at schedulerExecute (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:95:18)\n    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2970:14)\n    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2953:27)\n    at asyncRun (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2860:25)\n    at C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:676:7\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)",
                        "passed": false,
                        "expected": "asd"
                    },
                    {
                        "matcherName": "toContain",
                        "message": "Expected undefined to contain 'asd'.",
                        "stack": "Error: Failed expectation\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\test\\e2e\\specs\\test1__spec.js:31:21)\n    at C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:112:25\n    at new ManagedPromise (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:1067:7)\n    at ControlFlow.promise (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2396:12)\n    at schedulerExecute (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:95:18)\n    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2970:14)\n    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2953:27)\n    at asyncRun (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2860:25)\n    at C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:676:7\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)",
                        "passed": false,
                        "expected": "asd"
                    },
                    {
                        "matcherName": "toContain",
                        "message": "Expected undefined to contain 'asd'.",
                        "stack": "Error: Failed expectation\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\test\\e2e\\specs\\test1__spec.js:32:21)\n    at C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:112:25\n    at new ManagedPromise (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:1067:7)\n    at ControlFlow.promise (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2396:12)\n    at schedulerExecute (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:95:18)\n    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2970:14)\n    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2953:27)\n    at asyncRun (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2860:25)\n    at C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:676:7\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)",
                        "passed": false,
                        "expected": "asd"
                    },
                    {
                        "matcherName": "toContain",
                        "message": "Expected undefined to contain 'asd'.",
                        "stack": "Error: Failed expectation\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\test\\e2e\\specs\\test1__spec.js:33:21)\n    at C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:112:25\n    at new ManagedPromise (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:1067:7)\n    at ControlFlow.promise (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2396:12)\n    at schedulerExecute (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:95:18)\n    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2970:14)\n    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2953:27)\n    at asyncRun (C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2860:25)\n    at C:\\Users\\clain\\Documents\\dev\\mat\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:676:7\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)",
                        "passed": false,
                        "expected": "asd"
                    }
                ],
                "passedExpectations": [],
                "pendingReason": "",
                "status": "failed"
            }
        ]
    },
    "suite2": {
        "id": "suite2",
        "description": "test suite for dashboard",
        "fullName": "test suite for dashboard",
        "failedExpectations": [],
        "status": "finished",
        "specs": [
            {
                "id": "spec2",
                "description": "should be able to login and see the dashboard",
                "fullName": "test suite for dashboard should be able to login and see the dashboard",
                "failedExpectations": [],
                "passedExpectations": [],
                "pendingReason": "",
                "status": "passed"
            },
            {
                "id": "spec3",
                "description": "should be able to change options",
                "fullName": "test suite for dashboard should be able to change options",
                "failedExpectations": [],
                "passedExpectations": [],
                "pendingReason": "",
                "status": "passed"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give more information? For example, the JSON source and why you are designing a database taking it as a starting point.

Comment: sure. the json source is the output from a reporter from Jasmine Matchers, and the reason for adding this to a database, is for storing my protractor tests results (I'm a automation developer, with some express and angular knowledge, not much). Basically, I'm trying to build a reporter and learn.

Comment: Two questions: Can a "spec" be related to more than one suite? The "failedExpectations" in "suite" and "specs" is the same entity?

Comment: Each suite, represents a all the tests related to a run. each suite can have a number of tests. a test, is represented by a spec. a suite represents a number of tests (specs). each test(spec) can have a number of failed expectations (or none). I would be interested in storing the suite fullName and all the specs details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starting, you need to know that a specific database design problem, does not have an only solution and could have found several approaches depending on factors as technology to use or amount of data, just to mention some.

In your case, a simple approach could be defining three tables: one for storing Suites, another for Specs and the last one for the Expectations. Each of them will have a field in correspondence with the ones in the JSON. Also, the tables will be related between them. The "Suites" table will have a one-to-many relationship with the "Specs". That way we are defining that for one Suite, you will have many "Specs". The same way, the "Specs" table will have a one-to-many relationship with "Expectations" table, ensuring that for one spec you will have many expectations.

Now, you have to notice two things:

1. Since you said "I would be interested in storing the suite fullName and all the specs details", I didn't include any "Expectations" reference to "Suits" table, even when the JSON has a field with that label. Referencing the same table from two related tables will introduce a loop in the design which could be harmful in some contexts.
2. Also, you can see that I just created a table for Expectations without making any difference between Failed or Passed. That distinction is easily achieved with the Passed Boolean (BIT in SQL Server) field. It will define if the Expectation is Passed in case the value is True or Failed if is False.

I'm including some SQL Server code with the tables creation, in order to support the approach described:

```
CREATE TABLE Suites (
    SuiteId NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(max),
    FullName NVARCHAR(max),
    Status NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SuiteId),
);

CREATE TABLE Specs  (
    SpecId NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(max),
    FullName NVARCHAR(max),
    PendingReason NVARCHAR(max),
    Status NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SpecId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SpecsSuite FOREIGN KEY (SuiteId)
    REFERENCES Suites(SuiteId)
);

CREATE TABLE Expectations  (
    ExpId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MatcherName NVARCHAR(50),
    Expected NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Message NVARCHAR(max),
    Stack NVARCHAR(max),
    Passed BIT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ExpId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ExpectationsSpec FOREIGN KEY (SpecId)
    REFERENCES Specs(SpecId)
);
```

Comment: I will give it a shot, do my best, and report back.

Comment: I can't run the sql task to create the tables with this.. (running mysql not mariadb server)

Comment: @apple, I just included the SQL Server code, in order to make the solution clearer. Your question was purely based on design. You never mentioned which database engine you will use. Notice that even when they are similar, SQL Server and MySql have differences even in the syntax.